# How to convert View<doc> or Async<doc> to Doc in webSharper?

Tags: websharper, websharper.ui.next

Please, I am new to WebSharper does anyone know how I can convert View (doc) or Async (doc) to Doc in webSharper? I have tried to open "WebSharper.UI.Next.Client" but does not seem to be compatible with the Doc I am using. The code giving such error is the one I found on the WebSharper website https://try.websharper.com/snippet/adam.granicz/00003b

Answer (score 3):

On the conversions: the functions are `Doc.EmbedView` and `Doc.Async` respectively.

The problem with the references was that `WebSharper.UI` has another separate version still called on its earlier name `WebSharper.UI.Next` for back-compatibility in older projects. It is recommended to use `WebSharper.UI` only.

The snippet you have linked was not updated accordingly, I have done it now, and will check others too. The main differences are that `Next` is no longer used in the namespace names and default HTML combinators take attribute and children lists both (An empty div is now `div [] []` while previously there it was a `div []` or `divAttr [] []`).